# XrmToolBox Tools tab blank

Tags: xrmtoolbox

I recently switched laptops at my job and need to set up this new one like the last.  Wasn't a part of the last set up and don't have the same resources now.  When I install the XRM tool box, the only tools visible are the ones that come pre-installed.  I can't see any of the other ones.  Any guidance is helpful.

-Rob

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to go to the plugin store and redownload your plugins.  If you still have access to your old computer, you can also copy over all the files found in the XTB folder from the C:\Users<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\MscrmTools\XrmToolBox

Comment: I copied over the Plugins zip file, but every time I run the toolbox it deletes that zip file from the folder.  I'm using OneDrive to back all of this up.  Any ideas?

Comment: Copied the XTB folder over.  If I do them as individual files, it deletes the Plugin file. Even if I drop the whole folder in there, it still doesn't populate the available tools.  I'm looking in the XRMToolBox and looking to change the storage folder path.  It states to "add the following argument" followed by the argument, but that direction is rather ambiguous. Where does this argument go?  Any insight?

Comment: Hi Daryl- I installed an older release of the XRM toolbox and it seemed to fix my issue.  I was told the new version is a little "buggy".  I appreciate your time and insight sir.